# starting another activity causes "unfortunately <app name> has stopped" error on some devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm new in android programming and have a question:

Is it possible not setting android:id attribute for a android layout(LinearLayout) which has it's specific activity resource  causes "unfortunately  has stopped" error on some devices(specifically galaxy s3 and note) and no error on other devices?

when I tap the button to start secondpage.xml error appears on some devices.

secondpage.xml

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background1"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".secondpage" >

     <LinearLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="45dp"
         android:background="#306754"
         android:orientation="horizontal" >

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_back2"
        android:minHeight="75dp"
        android:minWidth="75dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/shive_parsi_textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:text="page header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 </LinearLayout>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
>

<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/background1"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView5"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_gravity="center"
     android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
     android:text="test text"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
     android:textColor="#C4A97E"
     android:textSize="21sp" />


   </LinearLayout>

  </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

above code does not have this attribute:

```
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
```

Comment: please post the error log

Comment: Why do you need id for a layout?? What are you trying to accomplish? Your question is confusing. Are you trying to open a new activity on the button click i.e. show second `secondpage.xml`on a button click?